# connectapi follow a post on chatter

Tags: connect-api

How can I create a link on a visualforce page that when I click it, it will follow that that post using the connectapi
Also how can I display the posts that I follow using the connectapi

Comment: It need a lots of code. I guess you didn't work with connectApi methods

Answer (score 0):

Like a post:

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/chatterapi/Content/quickreference_like_feed_item.htm

Follow a record:

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/chatterapi/Content/quickreference_follow_record.htm

Get a news feed:
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/chatterapi/Content/quickreference_get_news_feed.htm

Get a group or record feed:
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/chatterapi/Content/quickreference_get_group_feed.htm

Comment: Thanks but I'm not looking to post, I want to pass the params from a visualforce page to apex using connectapi.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to do, can you explain in more detail?